QGIS Symbology to have 2 subtypes
I have a layer called 'LaneC'
Within that layer there are two attributes (Lane and Bay)
Is there any way to symbolise so that when I click the layer LaneC, a dropdown is shown to show Lane (which is C) and then from that subtype another dropdown to show Bay (C101 etc)

Currently, I've added both attributes to the categorized symbology like so, but when I toggle 'C' on none of the features are coloured red? Even if all the bays (C101 etc) are toggled off. I'd expect all the bays to be coloured red and then when that is toggled off, they can each be toggled on/off in their yellowy colour


No "Bay"-attribute has the value C, hence none will be coloured red. Other than that, it is rather unclear, what your expected output should be.

You can use the rule based symbology for that.
Start with the categorized rendered, and set your yellow colors on the bay attribute. Then, change to rule based, each category is automatically transformed to a rule.
Add a new rule, name is All C (or whatever) and set a filter on the lane value, like lane='C'. Use the red color and make sure this rule is at the top of the rule set (drag it with the mouse).


